# Listview Single CHOICE MODE scrolling bug

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listView with singleChoice mode on it, and after I select an item an scroll through the list sometimes the selector hovers over different items. I have multiple row type layouts but I don't think that is the issue here. How can I stop this from happening? Thanks

```
    RoomDeviceListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

private static final int DEFAULT_LAYOUT = -1;
private static final int SECTION_LAYOUT = 100;
private static final int RELAY_LAYOUT = 0;
private static final int DIMMER_LAYOUT = 1;
private static final int HVAC_LAYOUT = 2;
private static final int HEATING_LAYOUT = 3;
private static final int BLIND_LAYOUT = 4;
private static final int RGB_LAYOUT = 5;
private static final int _4Z_LAYOUT = 6;
private static final int _4T_LAYOUT = 7;
private static final int _Z_AUDIO_LAYOUT = 8;

public List<Object> mDevices = new ArrayList<Object>();
private TreeSet<Integer> sectionHeader = new TreeSet<Integer>();
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
protected Context mContext;

public RoomDeviceListAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_device_relay);
    mContext = context;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void addItem(final Object item) {
    mDevices.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addSectionHeaderItem(final Object item) {
    mDevices.add(item);
    sectionHeader.add(mDevices.size() - 1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDevices.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return mDevices.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(sectionHeader.contains(position))
        return SECTION_LAYOUT;
    if(((BaseDevice)mDevices.get(position)).getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(AppGroup.RELAY_KEY))
        return RELAY_LAYOUT;
    if(((BaseDevice)mDevices.get(position)).getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(AppGroup.RGB_KEY))
        return RGB_LAYOUT;
    if(((BaseDevice)mDevices.get(position)).getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(AppGroup.DIMMER_KEY))
        return DIMMER_LAYOUT;
    if(((BaseDevice)mDevices.get(position)).getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(AppGroup.HVAC_KEY))
        return HVAC_LAYOUT;
    if(((BaseDevice)mDevices.get(position)).getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(AppGroup.HEATING_KEY))
        return HEATING_LAYOUT;
    if(((BaseDevice)mDevices.get(position)).getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(AppGroup.BLIND_KEY))
        return BLIND_LAYOUT;
    if(((BaseDevice)mDevices.get(position)).getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(AppGroup._4Z_KEY))
        return _4Z_LAYOUT;
    if(((BaseDevice)mDevices.get(position)).getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(AppGroup._4T_KEY))
        return _4T_LAYOUT;
    if(((BaseDevice)mDevices.get(position)).getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(AppGroup.BLIND_KEY))
        return BLIND_LAYOUT;
    if(((BaseDevice)mDevices.get(position)).getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(AppGroup._Z_AUDIO_KEY))
        return _Z_AUDIO_LAYOUT;
    return RELAY_LAYOUT;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    final Object device = mDevices.get(position);

    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case SECTION_LAYOUT:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_device_list_header, parent, false);
            holder.sectionName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sectionName);
            holder.sectionPowerButton = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sectionPower);

            holder.sectionName.setText(DeviceUtils.devicesDefaultNames.get(((BaseDevice) device).getKey()));

            setState(holder, SECTION_LAYOUT, computeSectionState(((BaseDevice) device).getKey()));

            holder.sectionPowerButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (mContext instanceof DeviceListAdapterCallback) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setSectionState(position, ((BaseDevice) device).getKey(), IState.ACTIVE_STATE);
                        } else {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setSectionState(position, ((BaseDevice) device).getKey(), IState.INACTIVE_STATE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            break;
        case RELAY_LAYOUT :
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_device_relay, parent, false);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);
            holder.powerButton = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.powerButton);
            if(device.getClass() == Relay.class) {
                holder.icon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(((Relay)device).getIcon()));
                holder.deviceName.setText(((Relay) device).getName());

                setState(holder, RELAY_LAYOUT, ((Relay)device).getState());
            }
            holder.powerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mContext instanceof DeviceListAdapterCallback) {
                        if (holder.powerButton.isChecked()) {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setState(((BaseDevice) device).getId(), IState.ACTIVE_STATE);
                        } else {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setState(((BaseDevice) device).getId(), IState.INACTIVE_STATE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            break;
        case RGB_LAYOUT :
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_device_rgb, parent, false);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);
            holder.powerButton = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.powerButton);
            if(device.getClass() == RGB.class) {
                holder.icon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(((RGB)device).getIcon()));
                holder.deviceName.setText(((RGB) device).getName());

                setState(holder, RGB_LAYOUT, ((RGB)device).getState());
            }
            holder.powerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mContext instanceof DeviceListAdapterCallback) {
                        if (holder.powerButton.isChecked()) {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setState(((BaseDevice) device).getId(), IState.ACTIVE_STATE);
                        } else {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setState(((BaseDevice) device).getId(), IState.INACTIVE_STATE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            break;
        case DIMMER_LAYOUT :
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_device_dimmer, parent, false);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);
            holder.modeIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modeIcon);
            holder.modeValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modeValue);
            holder.powerButton = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.powerButton);
            if(device.getClass() == Dimmer.class) {
                holder.icon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(((Dimmer) device).getIcon()));
                holder.deviceName.setText(((Dimmer) device).getName());
                holder.modeValue.setText(((Dimmer) device).formatPercentage(mContext));
                setState(holder, DIMMER_LAYOUT, ((Dimmer)device).getState());
            }

            holder.powerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mContext instanceof DeviceListAdapterCallback) {
                        if(holder.powerButton.isChecked()) {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setState(((BaseDevice) device).getId(), IState.ACTIVE_STATE, 100);
                        } else {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setState(((BaseDevice) device).getId(), IState.INACTIVE_STATE, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            break;
        case HVAC_LAYOUT :
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_device_hvac, parent, false);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.modeIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modeIcon);
            holder.fanIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fanIcon);
            holder.deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);
            holder.modeValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modeValue);
            holder.fanValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fanValue);
            holder.powerButton = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.powerButton);

            if(device.getClass() == HVAC.class) {
                holder.icon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(((HVAC) device).getIcon()));
                holder.modeIcon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(((HVAC) device).getMode().getIcon()));
                holder.modeValue.setText((((HVAC) device).getMode().formatValue(mContext)));
                if(((HVAC)device).getMode().getType() == ModuleModes.FAN_MODE) {
                    holder.fanIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.fanValue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    holder.fanIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.fanValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.fanIcon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(((HVAC) device).getFanSpeed().getIcon()));
                    holder.fanValue.setText((((HVAC) device).getFanSpeed().formatFanSpeed(true)));
                }

                holder.deviceName.setText(((HVAC)device).getName());
                setState(holder, HVAC_LAYOUT, ((HVAC) device).getState());
            }
            holder.powerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mContext instanceof DeviceListAdapterCallback) {
                        if (holder.powerButton.isChecked()) {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setState(((BaseDevice) device).getId(), IState.ACTIVE_STATE);
                        } else {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setState(((BaseDevice) device).getId(), IState.INACTIVE_STATE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            break;
        case HEATING_LAYOUT :
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_device_heating, parent, false);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);
            holder.powerButton = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.powerButton);
            holder.modeIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modeIcon);
            holder.modeValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modeValue);
            if(device.getClass() == Heating.class) {
                holder.icon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(((Heating)device).getIcon()));
                holder.deviceName.setText(((Heating) device).getName());
                holder.modeIcon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(((Heating) device).getMode().getIcon()));
                holder.modeValue.setText((((Heating) device).getMode().formatValue(mContext)));
                setState(holder, HEATING_LAYOUT, ((Heating) device).getState());
            }
            holder.powerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mContext instanceof DeviceListAdapterCallback) {
                        if (holder.powerButton.isChecked()) {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setState(((BaseDevice) device).getId(), IState.ACTIVE_STATE);
                        } else {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setState(((BaseDevice) device).getId(), IState.INACTIVE_STATE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            break;

        case BLIND_LAYOUT :
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_device_blinds, parent, false);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);
            holder.modeIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modeIcon);
            holder.modeValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modeValue);
            holder.blindsOpenButton = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.blindsOn);
            holder.blindsCloseButton = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.blindsOff);
            if(device.getClass() == Blind.class) {
                holder.icon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(((Blind) device).getIcon()));
                holder.deviceName.setText(((Blind) device).getName());
                holder.modeIcon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(((Blind) device).getMode().getIcon()));
                holder.modeValue.setText(((Blind) device).getMode().getName());
                holder.modeIcon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(((Blind) device).getMode().getIcon()));
                holder.modeValue.setText(((Blind) device).getMode().getName());
                setState(holder, BLIND_LAYOUT, ((Blind) device).getState(), ((Blind) device).getMode());
            }

            holder.blindsOpenButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (mContext instanceof DeviceListAdapterCallback) {
                        if(holder.blindsCloseButton.isChecked()) {
                            holder.blindsCloseButton.setChecked(false);
                        }
                        if(isChecked) {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setState(((BaseDevice) device).getId(), IState.ACTIVE_STATE, DeviceModeLists.getModeByType(((Blind) device).getDeviceModes(), ModuleModes.BLINDS_OPEN_MODE));
                        } else {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setState(((BaseDevice) device).getId(), IState.INACTIVE_STATE, DeviceModeLists.getModeByType(((Blind)device).getDeviceModes(), ModuleModes.BLINDS_OPEN_MODE));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.blindsCloseButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (mContext instanceof DeviceListAdapterCallback) {
                        if (holder.blindsOpenButton.isChecked()) {
                            holder.blindsOpenButton.setChecked(false);
                        }
                        if (isChecked) {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setState(((BaseDevice) device).getId(), IState.ACTIVE_STATE, DeviceModeLists.getModeByType(((Blind) device).getDeviceModes(), ModuleModes.BLINDS_CLOSE_MODE));
                        } else {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setState(((BaseDevice) device).getId(), IState.INACTIVE_STATE, DeviceModeLists.getModeByType(((Blind) device).getDeviceModes(), ModuleModes.BLINDS_CLOSE_MODE));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            break;

        case _4Z_LAYOUT:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_device_4z, parent, false);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);
            holder.status = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);

            if(device.getClass() == _4Z.class) {
                holder.icon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(((BaseDevice)device).getIcon()));
                holder.deviceName.setText(((BaseDevice) device).getName());
                setState(holder, _4Z_LAYOUT, ((BaseDevice) device).getState());
                if(((_4Z)device).isHasError()) {
                    holder.status.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.atentie));
                } else {
                    holder.status.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ok));
                }
            }
            break;
        case _4T_LAYOUT:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_device_4t, parent, false);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);
            holder.modeValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modeValue);
            holder.modeIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modeIcon);
            holder.status = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);


            if(device.getClass() == _4T.class) {
                holder.icon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(((BaseDevice)device).getIcon()));
                holder.deviceName.setText(((BaseDevice) device).getName());
                holder.modeValue.setText(String.valueOf(((_4T) device).getValue()));
                setState(holder, _4T_LAYOUT, ((BaseDevice) device).getState());
                if(((_4T)device).isHasError()) {
                    holder.status.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.atentie));
                } else {
                    holder.status.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ok));
                }
            }
            break;
        case _Z_AUDIO_LAYOUT:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_z_audio, parent, false);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);


            if(device.getClass() == _zAudio.class) {
                holder.icon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(((BaseDevice)device).getIcon()));
                holder.deviceName.setText(((BaseDevice) device).getName());
                setState(holder, _Z_AUDIO_LAYOUT, ((BaseDevice) device).getState());
            }
            break;
        default:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_device_relay, parent, false);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);
            holder.powerButton = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.powerButton);
            if(device.getClass() == BaseDevice.class) {
                holder.icon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(((BaseDevice)device).getIcon()));
                holder.deviceName.setText(((BaseDevice) device).getName());
                setState(holder, DEFAULT_LAYOUT, ((BaseDevice) device).getState());
            }
            holder.powerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mContext instanceof DeviceListAdapterCallback) {
                        if (holder.powerButton.isChecked()) {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setState(((BaseDevice) device).getId(), IState.ACTIVE_STATE);
                        } else {
                            ((DeviceListAdapterCallback) mContext).setState(((BaseDevice) device).getId(), IState.INACTIVE_STATE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            break;
    }

    return convertView;
}

    static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView icon;
    TextView deviceName;
    ImageView modeIcon;
    TextView modeValue;
    ImageView fanIcon;
    ImageView status;
    TextView fanValue;
    ToggleButton powerButton;
    ToggleButton blindsOpenButton;
    ToggleButton blindsCloseButton;
    TextView sectionName;
    ToggleButton sectionPowerButton;
}
```

}

Comment: please post your adapter code

Comment: most likely a view recycling issue. Please post your adapter code.

Comment: Check your Viewholder pattern, there is too much code.